# How to proper use reduce() javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, reduce

1. I try to solve task below with reduce() and actually the result is ok. But I don't know how to use acc in reduce() instead of acc1 or indexMax.
2. How to apply typescript to this task.

The task:
**Find first word with max repeated letter count.** For example **rrrtygggg** and **ttbvfddjklyyyaseqq** - the winner is **rrrtygggg**.
If sequence has no repeated letters return 'false'.
Count only letters, ignor digits and special chars.

Here is my solution.
Also I need to keep time complexity not higher than n. The most important part for me is `reduce()` and `acc`.

```
const maxLettersInString =(str)=>{
        let acc1={};
        let indexMax;
        let ind=0;
        let n=0;

        const newStr = str.replace(/[^a-z\s]/gi,'')
        const arr = str.split(' ');
        if(arr.length===0) return false;
        const arr1 = newStr.split('');

        const result = arr1.reduce((acc,x)=>{
            if(x!==' '){
                acc1[x] ? acc1[x]++ : acc1[x] = 1;
                if(acc1[x]>n) n=acc1[x], indexMax=ind;
            }
            if(x===' ') acc1={}, ind+=1;
            else return indexMax;
        })

        if(n===1) return false
        return arr[result]
    }
console.log(maxLettersInString('fdsJJHHBldfkfd +=dfsfds tbrlllLLtrbtrbrLL666667777LLtlllllll----- fdsfs66df7758 tRbrerbrrtRR'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the original words, with two outer variables:

- One with a count of the maximum number of repeated letters found so far (starts at 0), and
- The string corresponding to the count found above

All you need is a simple loop - on each iteration, calculate the repeat count for the current word being iterated over, and if it's higher than the record so far, reassign the two outer variables.

```js
const getRepeatCount = (str) => {
    const repeatCounts = {};
    for (const char of str.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, '')) {
        repeatCounts[char] = (repeatCounts[char] ?? -1) + 1;
    }
    return Math.max(...Object.values(repeatCounts));
};
const maxLettersInString = (str) => {
    let maxRepeatsFoundSoFar = 0;
    let bestWordSoFar = '';
    for (const word of str.split(' ')) {
        const repeatCount = getRepeatCount(word);
        if (repeatCount > maxRepeatsFoundSoFar) {
            maxRepeatsFoundSoFar = repeatCount;
            bestWordSoFar = word;
        }
    }
    return bestWordSoFar === '' ? false : bestWordSoFar;
};
console.log(maxLettersInString('rrrtygggg and ttbvfddjklyyyaseqq'));
```

To turn it into TypeScript, just add `: string` to the parameter types and `: Record<string, number>` to the `repeatCounts` object.

This would be possible to do with `.reduce` if the accumulator was an object with two properties, `maxRepeatsFoundSoFar` and `bestWordSoFar` instead of outer variables - but the typing and syntax noise would be annoying, outer variables are easier.

Comment: My mistake, task should be: Find first word with max **repeated** letter count.

Comment: If that's what you need, `.reduce` wouldn't be be an appropriate tool. It's *possible* to use, but would look quite cumbersome and unwieldy compared to a simple loop and outside variables. Is `.reduce` really required due to assignment constraints or something?

Comment: But ```if(x===' ')``` is working and is executed every "space" char because ```const newStr = str.replace(/[^a-z\sgi,'')``` keep spaces between words.

Comment: ```.reduce``` is not required. It is only my idea because I try to understand this method. Is this possible to show me better way?

Comment: If you test task with ```'fdsJJHHBldfkfd rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr +=dfsfds tbrlllLLtrbtrbrLL666667777LLtlllllll----- fdsfs66df7758 tRbrerbrrtRR'``` is not working corectly. Also here is nested loop so the time complexity is ```n^2```.

Comment: The word returned for that is `tbrlllLLtrbtrbrLL666667777LLtlllllll` because there are 22 repeated characters, which is more than that of any of the other words in the input. Why do you say that isn't the desired output?

Comment: Although there is a nested loop here, the inner loop only iterates over each character in the input once, so it's definitely `O(n)`. The time required for the algorithm increases linearly with the length of the input string.

Comment: I update task again: For example **rrrtygggg** and **ttbvfddjklyyyaseqq** - the winner is **rrrtygggg**. You are right, is 0(n).

Comment: `ttbvfddjklyyyaseqq` has very few repeats - `t` repeats `t` once, `d` once, `y` twice, and `q` once. Total of of 5. `rrrtygggg` repeats `r` twice and `g` 3 times. Total of 5 - so they're the same in the eyes of the algorithm, and the first one found wins (`rrrtygggg`) - which is what you wanted, right?

Comment: Because **g** is repeated 3 times **rrrtygggg** wins.

Comment: OK, then use `Math.max` to find the highest number in the character mapping instead of `.reduce` to add them all up...

Comment: Can I declare ```: object``` instead of ```Record<string, number>```?

Comment: No, `object` is too general - using it results in the object not being seen as having an index signature with the `char`.